# How to get system locale and system language in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslocale

I want to get the system default language and system locale.

I have tried the following code snippet to get the system current locale as the following

```
NSLocale *locale;
locale = [NSLocale systemLocale];

NSString * localLanguage = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
NSLog (@"Language : %@", localLanguage); 

NSLog(@"System locale Identifier %@",[locale localeIdentifier]);
```

But nothing is displayed with System locale Identifier.If it is currentlocale it is giving the correct result.Why system locale is not giving any value and how to get system default language not the user preferred language?please help

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use:
`NSString* language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 5):

The default `NSLocaleIdentifier` is intentionally `@""` to indicate that there is no current selection.    According to Apple, `systemLocale` is just a fallback for keys that aren't implemented in the user's selected locale (`currentLocale`), and since that's always set and it's always under the user's control, it makes sense.

If you want to follow the user's list of preferred languages, you want to use `+ preferredLanguages`, which returns a list of the languages that the user prefers, in the order in which they prefer them.   This works for both OSX and iOS, and serves to provide an appropriate fallback for the system when choosing languages.

For testing, you can use the command-line switch `-AppleLanguages` with a value of a comma-separated, parenthesis-surrounded array (example: `(DE,FR,EN)`) and Xcode will simulate that being the preferred languages list for the user.

Since the user sets the preferred languages (at least in OSX), the operating system will follow the list when it chooses localized data for the user.   Generally, doing anything more than using the macros is considered unnecessary due to this fact.  However, you can manually look at the value if you have non-resource information you need to localize.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Do you have any idea how can I get system language.

Comment: There really isn't one for OS X.  It's all determined by the user.   What are you trying to use it for?  Maybe there's another mechanism that I can point you to.

Comment: My req. is to display the text in user preferred language,it is fetched from the backend services,if the user is not chosen specific language,then I need to display the text in default system language.Thats why I am trying to find out how can I fetch the system default language.Can you please tell me what is the other mechanism?

Comment: I've added some more information on the trickle-down mechanism using preferredLanguages.